# append time lapse image to video file

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I want to grab an image from a usb camera every 2 seconds and save it in a video file. The problem with this as I see it is: the video file will not be closed if the pc/laptop goes down or stops for some reason - and all images will be lost.

My question is: is there a way of appending each captured image to the video file and closing the file again to avoid loss? Opencv doesnt appear to offer this feature - nor SFML.

Im developing in ubuntu using g++ and SFML.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before. To be honest with you, I did not make a deep search about it. I am pretty sure there are some undocumented part of the `video writer` that may contain what you are looking for. However, I can provide you with a tricky solution that works well for small videos. Save each `cv::Mat` into `std::vector` and each frame (or each n frames), `serialize` the `vector` to the `hard disk`. Then, clear the `vector` totally. After you finished, `deserialize` all the data and write it once to a video file using OpenCV `video writer`.

Anyway, it is not good to do it like I wrote. there should be another solution. You may dig into the OpenCV code and see what is happening in the `destructor` of the `videoWriter` class.